# Combine two columns and join on one MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following columns
Table A: name, start_date, end_date
Table B: name, date_range

Table B date_range is a combination of the start_date and end_date of Table A.

```
SELECT tableB.date_range,
CONCAT(tableA.start_date, tableA.end_date) AS date_range 
FROM tableB
INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.date_range=date_range
```

I'm very new to MySQL and would like help in how to join these two tables please?

Comment: Please write desired output because we can't understand what you are trying to accomplish with what you exposed.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're doing it like this instead of having a foreign key on TableB that references TableA? That way, if either the start or end date changes, you only need to update the TableA record.

Comment: I need to do it this way as a lot of the data is loaded via excel sheets so needs to be readable

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Seriously consider revising this design - especially if your data set is likely to get significantly larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but you would have to have the concatenation in the join criteria instead.

```
SELECT tableB.date_range,
  FROM tableB
  JOIN tableA ON tableB.date_range=CONCAT(tableA.start_date, tableA.end_date)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Andreas this worked a treat. So simple too!

Comment: No problem and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Don't forget to up vote any answers you find that helps you (not only on own questions) and to accept the best answer on your own questions.